# I want to split a string by a character on its first occurence, which belongs to a list of characters. How to do this in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

Basically, I have a list of special characters. I need to split a string by a character if it belongs to this list and exists in the string. Something on the lines of:

```
def find_char(string):

  if string.find("some_char"):
     #do xyz with some_char
  elif string.find("another_char"):
     #do xyz with another_char
  else:
     return False
```

and so on. The way I think of doing it is:

```
def find_char_split(string):
     char_list = [",","*",";","/"]
     for my_char in char_list:
         if string.find(my_char) != -1:
             my_strings = string.split(my_char)
             break
         else:
             my_strings = False

     return my_strings
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this? Or the above procedure would be fine? Please help, I'm not very proficient in python.

(EDIT): I want it to split on the first occurrence of the character, which is encountered first. That is to say, if the string contains multiple commas, and multiple stars, then **I want it to split by the first occurrence of the comma**. Please note, if the star comes first, then it will be broken by the star.

Comment: For this kind of thing I would favor the split function in the regex module (`re` module).

Comment: Right... so is `abc,*def,xyz` equal to `['abc', '*def,xyz']` or `['abc', '*def', 'xyz']` ?

Comment: @JonClements that would be the former. The second one is an invalid case for the purpose of my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would favor using the `re` module for this because the expression for splitting on multiple arbitrary characters is very simple:

```
r'[,*;/]'
```

The brackets create a character class that matches anything inside of them. The code is like this:

```
import re

results = re.split(r'[,*;/]', my_string, maxsplit=1)
```

The `maxsplit` argument makes it so that the split only occurs once.

If you are doing the same split many times, you can compile the regex and search on that same expression a little bit faster (but see [Jon Clements' comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964991/i-want-to-split-a-string-by-a-character-on-its-first-occurence-which-belongs-t/45966239?noredirect=1#comment78892299_45966239)):

```
c = re.compile(r'[,*;/]')
results = c.split(my_string)
```

If this speed up is important (it probably isn't) you can use the compiled version in a function instead of having it re compile every time. Then make a separate function that stores the actual compiled expression:

```
def split_chars(chars, maxsplit=0, flags=0, string=None):
    # see note about the + symbol below
    c = re.compile('[{}]+'.format(''.join(chars)), flags=flags)
    def f(string, maxsplit=maxsplit):
        return c.split(string, maxsplit=maxsplit)
    return f if string is None else f(string)
```

Then:

```
special_split = split_chars(',*;/', maxsplit=1)
result = special_split(my_string)
```

But also:

```
result = split_chars(',*;/', my_string, maxsplit=1)
```

The purpose of the `+` character is to treat multiple delimiters as one if that is desired (thank you Jon Clements). If this is not desired, you can just use `re.compile('[{}]'.format(''.join(chars)))` above. Note that with `maxsplit=1`, this will not have any effect.

Finally: have a look at [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abrcJ9MpF60) for a quick introduction to regular expressions in Python, and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sOfhhduqks) for a much more information packed journey.

Comment: Instead of or'ing these you use a character class that'll also avoid escaping... `re.split(r'[,*/;]+', my_string)`... and adding the `+` there to treat consecutive delimiter characters a one - which may or may not be required depending...

Comment: @JonClements very good points. I've only just recently started using regex myself.

Comment: Also - the speed up by using compiled regexes isn't necessarily as great as one is led to believe... The `re` engine keeps a certain amount of them interned for lookup, so if you're using the same string constant it already re-uses a compiled expression for you.

Comment: @Jon Clements, actually the reason I did not use regex is, that it would split the string everywhere if it encounters one or more of the character mentioned in the pattern. I need it to split it on the first occurrence of any of the characters in the given list. By that I mean, if a comma is there, and a star is there, and the comma comes first, then split it by the comma, not the star. The regex would split it with both the comma and the star.

Comment: @Shrey you didn't mention that in your question. You can provide a max_split argument to `re.split` to only split once... Or are you saying that you want to split on all occurrences of the first occurrence of a certain character?

Comment: @JonClements I am sorry for that. I have added the EDIT to my original post. I want it to split by the **first occurrence of the first character** and that character can be anyone from the list given. I hope that I have explained the issue better now.

Comment: @shrey Just for the sake of understanding: it were the latter case,  the regex in the answer with the termination + symbol ignores multiple delimiters of all the characters. I'll edit so that there is an occurrence parameter. Not too difficult.

Comment: @ShreyMarwaha based on your response to my comment on your Q, it looks like `re.split('[,*;/]', 'abc,*def,xyz;whatever', maxsplit=1)` will do you - so you can use this answer.

Comment: @RickTeachey, yes I tried it locally, and it is an excellent solution to the latter case. Thanks to you and both Jon for that. But unfortunately, the second case is invalid for the purpose of my code.

Comment: @Shrey doesn't supplying the `maxsplit=` do what you want then?

Comment: @RickTeachey, YES THAT DOES IT! Thanks a ton for this thread, and to Jon Clements to for his advice! Also, the previous comment was for your earlier comment, don't mind it :)